# org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of

Tags: hibernate, spring-security

i face a problem shown below

```java
IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of org.springframework.security.oauth.examples.sparklr.models.Authority.user; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: 
IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of org.springframework.security.oauth.examples.sparklr.models.Authority.user
```

my hibernate dependencies are:

- hibernate-core 3.3.2.GA
- hibernate-annotations 3.4.0.GA
- hibernate-commons-annotations 3.3.0.ga
- hibernate-entitymanager 3.4.0.GA

```java
public class User implements UserDetails,Serializable {

    /** Serial Version UID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -558892839L;

    /** Use a WeakHashMap so entries will be garbage collected once all entities 
        referring to a saved hash are garbage collected themselves. */
    private static final Map<Serializable, String> SAVED_HASHES =
        Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<Serializable, String>());

    /** hashCode temporary storage. */
    private volatile String hashCode;


    /** Field mapping. */
    private Boolean accountnonexpired;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private Boolean accountnonlocked;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private List<Authority> authorities = new ArrayList<Authority>();

    /** Field mapping. */
    private Boolean credentialsnonexpired;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private Boolean enabled;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private String id;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private String password;


       public class Authority implements Serializable ,GrantedAuthority {


    /** Serial Version UID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -558892840L;

    /** Use a WeakHashMap so entries will be garbage collected once all entities 
        referring to a saved hash are garbage collected themselves. */
    private static final Map<Serializable, Serializable> SAVED_HASHES =
        Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<Serializable, Serializable>());

    /** hashCode temporary storage. */
    private volatile Serializable hashCode;


    /** Field mapping. */
    private String authority;
    /** Field mapping. */
    private User user;
```

how can i solve thank you so much

Comment: You haven't shown us the `org.springframework.security.oauth.examples.sparklr.models.Authority` class, which seems to be the source of the exception.

Comment: i posted below my authority class can you have a look please thank you

Answer (score 0):

from the code you have shown, you don't have a getter for the `user` property of `Authority`.

Try adding

```
public User getUser(){
    return this.user;
}
```

Comment: i have but i cant copy all code because of  company restriction ,it blocks                                                   @ManyToOne( cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
 @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
 @JoinColumn(name = "user", nullable = false )
        @Id
 public User getUser() {
  return this.user;
  
 }

Comment: iam not sure hibernate version,is it ok?

Comment: when i change these dependencies with  hsqldb 2.0.0,hibernate-jmx 3.5.4-Final,hibernate-annotations 3.3.0.ga,hibernate-commons-annotations 3.3.0.ga,javassist 3.4.GA i faced with below error java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.hibernate.cfg.ExtendedMapping
 has interface org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings as super class  -------  if i add hibernate-entitymanager 3.4.0.GA  other error is same     IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of ---same with first i dont understand